# How to check disks at startup (alternative to chkdsk c: /f on Windows)

Tags: linux-mint, disk, fsck

How to check my two disks at startup (they're in BIOS RAID 1)?

I am on Linux Mint 17.2.

```
computer user # blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="6042-870C" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="2ef42e6f-4987-46e5-aca9-872fd70a9f9e" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="Oz0elc-zUuh-BAK1-i19b-RZZU-YREm-DxVaNi" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="6042-870C" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="2ef42e6f-4987-46e5-aca9-872fd70a9f9e" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sdb3: UUID="Oz0elc-zUuh-BAK1-i19b-RZZU-YREm-DxVaNi" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: UUID="98a7a4a2-6e71-4aa9-ab48-5c4fc619c321" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1: UUID="b62721cf-7b54-4400-92f0-f8f776566c99" TYPE="swap"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at startup" ?

Comment: It's done automatically. You can check your `/etc/fstab` (and do a `man fstab` before that), the last number on a fstab line is about fsck (put 1 on the root filesystem, 2 on others, or 0 if you don't want the bother).

Comment: Also check out `tune2fs` on ext filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

Then reboot this machine normally.

Comment: This does not work as proven here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400927/126755

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it works, but you can try:

```
shutdown -rF now
```

`-r` means reboot.
`-F` means force filesystem check.

you can take a look at the manual of shutdown command.

Comment: This does not work as proven here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400927/126755