# What should I do to force the root filesystem check (and optionally a fix) at boot?

Tags: linux, ext4, fsck

Yesterday, one of our computers dropped to `grub` shell or honestly, I am unsure what shell it was when we turned on the machine.

It showed that it can't mount the root filesystem or something in this sense, because of inconsistencies.

I ran, I believe:

```
fsck -fy /dev/sda2
```

Rebooted and the problem was gone.

Here comes the question part:

I already have in her root's crontab:

> ```
> @reboot /home/ruzena/Development/bash/fs-check.sh
> ```

while the script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /forcefsck
```

Thinking about it, I don't know, why I created script file for such a short command, but anyways...

Further, in the file:

```
/etc/default/rcS
```

I have defined:

> ```
> FSCKFIX=yes
> ```

So I don't get it. How could the situation even arise?

---

What should I do to force the root filesystem check (and optionally a fix) at boot?

Or are these two things the maximum, that I can do?

**OS:** Linux Mint 18.x Cinnamon 64-bit.

**`fstab`:**

```
cat /etc/fstab | grep ext4
```

shows:

> ```
> UUID=a121371e-eb12-43a0-a5ae-11af58ad09f4    /    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
> ```

**`grub`:**

> ```
> fsck.mode=force
> ```

was already added to the `grub` configuration.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## `ext4` filesystem check during boot

Tested on OS: Linux Mint 18.x in a Virtual Machine

## Basic information

`/etc/fstab` has the `fsck` order as the last (6th) column, for instance:

```
<file system>    <mount point>    <type>    <options>    <dump>    <fsck>
UUID=2fbcf5e7-1234-abcd-88e8-a72d15580c99 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

---

`FSCKFIX=yes` variable in `/etc/default/rcS`

This will change the fsck to auto fix, but *not* force a fsck check.

From `man rcS`:

> ```
> FSCKFIX
>     When  the  root  and all other file systems are checked, fsck is
>     invoked with the -a option which means "autorepair".   If  there
>     are  major  inconsistencies then the fsck process will bail out.
>     The system will print a  message  asking  the  administrator  to
>     repair  the  file  system manually and will present a root shell
>     prompt (actually a sulogin prompt) on the console.  Setting this
>     option  to  yes  causes  the fsck commands to be run with the -y
>     option instead of the -a option.  This will tell fsck always  to
>     repair the file systems without asking for permission.
> ```

---

From `man tune2fs`

> ```
> If you are using journaling on your filesystem, your filesystem
> will never be marked dirty, so it will not normally be checked.
> ```

---

## Start with

Setting the following

> ```
> FSCKFIX=yes
> ```

in the file

```
/etc/default/rcS
```

Check and note last time fs was checked:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep "Last checked"
```

---

## These two options did NOT work

1. **Passing `-F` (force `fsck` on reboot) argument to `shutdown`:**

   ```
   shutdown -rF now
   ```

   Nope; see: `man shutdown`.
2. **Adding the `/forcefsck` empty file with:**

   ```
   touch /forcefsck
   ```

   These scripts seem to use this:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/checkfs.sh
   /etc/init.d/checkroot.sh
   ```

   did **NOT** work on reboot, but the file was deleted.

   *Verified by:*

   ```
   sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep "Last checked"
   sudo less /var/log/fsck/checkfs
   sudo less /var/log/fsck/checkroot
   ```

   These seem to be the logs for the `init` scripts.

**I repeat, these two options did NOT work!**

---

## Both of these methods DID work

1. **[systemd-fsck](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html) kernel boot switches**

   Editing the main `grub` configuration file:

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   > ```
   > GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="fsck.mode=force"
   > ```

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   sudo reboot
   ```

   This did do a file system check as verified with:

   ```
   sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep "Last checked"
   ```

   Note: This **DID** a check, but to force a fix too, you need to specify `fsck.repair="preen"`, or `fsck.repair="yes"`.
2. **Using `tune2fs` to set the number of file system mounts before doing a `fsck`, `man tune2fs`**

   > ```
   > tune2fs' info is kept in the file system superblock
   > ```

   `-c` switch sets the number of times to mount the fs before checking the fs.

   ```
   sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda1
   ```

   Verify with:

   ```
   sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
   ```

   This **DID** work as verified with:

   ```
   sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep "Last checked"
   ```

---

## Summary

To force a `fsck` on every boot on Linux Mint 18.x, use either `tune2fs`, or `fsck.mode=force`, with optional `fsck.repair=preen` / `fsck.repair=yes`, the kernel command line switches.

Comment: On a Grub-based Debian system, consider creating `/etc/default/grub.d/local.cfg` file with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT fsck.mode=force"`. This will avoid need to merge `/etc/default/grub` config file during upgrades.

Comment: This is a *fantastic* answer - but I think that the command towards the end should be using `-i` not `-c`. `-i` sets the check interval - and `-c` sets the maximum mount count.

Answer (score 6):

### Further investigation and updates on the existing answer

I now just wanted to check, whether the above still works on **Ubuntu 20.04/22.04-LTS-based systems** (directly tested on Linux Mint 20/21 Cinnamon <sup>amd64 desktop</sup> and Ubuntu MATE 20.04/22.04 <sup>amd64 desktop</sup>), and I found out a few things, let's start with the file system check interval (I ran all commands as root (as you might notice `~#` in front of commands):

---

### File system check interval

```
~# LC_ALL=C tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p2 | grep 'Check interval'

Check interval:           0 (<none>)
```

Well, this was unexpected. I thought we took care of it, but can be fixed very easily. Take note, the number it takes as an argument is by default in days, so be sure to use 1s (1 seconds) instead of just 1 which would mean 1 day (86400 seconds):

```
~# LC_ALL=C tune2fs -i 1s /dev/nvme0n1p2

tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Setting interval between checks to 1 seconds
```

Now, if we repeat the above check, we get:

```
Check interval:           1 (0:00:01)
```

This does not mean the file system will be checked every second, of course. Rather, in effect it will force the file system check on every file system mount. (As there is no way of booting any system twice in one second .)

---

### File system maximum number of mounts before check

Default setting:

```
~# LC_ALL=C tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p2 | grep 'Maximum mount count'

Maximum mount count:      -1
```

This setting adjusts how many mounts it takes till the file system gets checked. It's ok what is written in the original answer:

```
~# LC_ALL=C tune2fs -c 1 /dev/nvme0n1p2

tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Setting maximal mount count to 1
```

Just make sure you do not use 0 or -1 as it would become disregarded.

**---**

### Combination of both - The recommended way

Here you only change your disk name (e.g. `sda`, `vda`, `nvme0n1`, etc.), and partition number:

**First**, we find out the current status with:

```bash
partition=/dev/nvme0n1p2; LC_ALL=C tune2fs -l $partition | grep -E 'Check\ interval|Maximum\ mount\ count'
```

=

```
Maximum mount count:      -1
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
```

**Afterward**, we set these values so that the file system is checked on every boot with:

```bash
partition=/dev/nvme0n1p2; LC_ALL=C tune2fs -i 1s -c 1 $partition 2>&1 | grep Setting
```

=

```
Setting maximal mount count to 1
Setting interval between checks to 1 seconds
```

**Finally**, let's review the new status with the same *first* command:

```bash
partition=/dev/nvme0n1p2; LC_ALL=C tune2fs -l $partition | grep -E 'Check\ interval|Maximum\ mount\ count'
```

=

```
Maximum mount count:      1
Check interval:           1 (0:00:01)
```

---

Information sources:

- [`tune2fs` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs)

---

**Keep checking (pun intended)!**