# fsck not performed during boot in spite fstab configured correctly

Tags: linux, rhel, fstab, reboot, fsck

today we notice about very strange issue

the following partition  ( from /etc/fstab) defined with "2" in the end of the line

**that means that fsck will be activate during boot**

*since the data on that partition is 24T*

that means that reboot should be take around couple hours or more

but reboot actually takes 4 min !!!

from /etc/fstab

```
“UUID=7eab43c-41ba-1331-8ab7-a538326a5b8e /BD_APP    xfs     rw,noatime,inode64,allocsize=16m 1 2”
```

how we explian this strange thing?

why fsck was not "on" during boot ?

Comment: Will this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400851/what-should-i-do-to-force-the-root-filesystem-check-and-optionally-a-fix-at-bo/400927#400927) help? It is for `ext4` file system, but may have useful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to `man fsck.xfs`

> XFS is a journaling filesystem and performs recovery at mount(8) time if necessary, so fsck.xfs simply exits with a zero exit status.

as man suggest try `xfs_repair`

There is no need to fsck as recovery is performed at mount time.

Comment: so let me summary what you said , what is configured in my fstab will not do nothing ( its mean fsck will not performed ) , second in order to do real fsck to /dev/sdb we need to do xfs_repair , am I correct ?

Comment: second question , if this is the case then what we need to change in the fstab to perform fsck during boot ?

Comment: another note we have redhat version 6.x