# Constantly I have to use `fsck` to fix my PC

Tags: hard-disk, fsck

It isn't the first time I have this kind of error. I was using my computer (Ubuntu 3.2) when my file permissions turned to `read-only`, so I restarted the computer, it wasn't finishing turning on, so I forced to turn it off (hard power off), and I was turning it on again, and I saw this:

```
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCOSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
          (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck


BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I wrote `fsck /dev/sda2` (with `-a` because i don't know how to do it without that), I am worried because this is not the first time, maybe the hard-disk is broken or I don't know. Maybe this is not the best place for my problem. Will you tell me what to do? What is it next? I want to learn, so your suggestions are too helpful.

P.D.: Sorry for my English

I wrote `fsck /dev/sda2`, and the next was:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were of a corrupted orphan linked list found. Fix<y>?
```

I put `y` and the screen prints:

```
Inode 18874440 was part of the orphaned inode list. FIXED
Inode 18874445 was part of the orphaned inode list. FIXED
Inode 18874466 was part of the orphaned inode list. FIXED
```

And 20 lines of that, the following was

```
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences: -(2494976--2495023) - (so many numbers)....
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #76 (19099, counted 19147).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #81 (30339, counted=30365)
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1577 (28430, counted=28437)
Fix<y>? yes
...
```

Finally

```
/dev/sda2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda2: 541701/61022208 files (0.4% non-contiguous),  18674207/244059136 blocks
```

After of this, I wrote `reboot` and the computer came back to work. But this will happens again, and I need stop it.

I need some book to invetigate this, i want to learn why this happens.

---

**Update:**
It happens again, when I was using Mozilla Firefox, the files' permissions were turned to `read only`. Then I restart the pc, and it doesn't finish. I will have to restart it and use `fsck` again.

---

**Output of `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` :**

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.3.0-42-generic] (local build) 
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org 

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION === 
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ04ABF100 
Serial Number:    X8JBP3K2T 
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 8d268714d 
Firmware Version: JU001J 
User Capacity:    1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB] 
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical 
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm 
Form Factor:      2.5 inches 
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall] 
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5 
SATA Version is:  SATA >3.2 (0x1ff), 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s) 
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 29 03:48:34 2020 -03 
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability. 
SMART support is: Enabled 

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION === 
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED 

General SMART Values: 
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity 
                    was never started. 
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled. 
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed 
                    without error or no self-test has ever  
                    been run. 
Total time to complete Offline  
data collection:        (  120) seconds. 
Offline data collection 
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate. 
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support. 
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new 
                    command. 
                    Offline surface scan supported. 
                    Self-test supported. 
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported. 
                    Selective Self-test supported. 
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering 
                    power-saving mode. 
                    Supports SMART auto save timer. 
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported. 
                    General Purpose Logging supported. 
Short self-test routine  
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes. 
Extended self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    ( 172) minutes. 
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported. 
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported. 
                    SCT Feature Control supported. 
                    SCT Data Table supported. 

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16 
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds: 
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE 
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0 
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0 
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1348 
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       596 
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0 
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   095   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0 
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0 
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       1544 
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   111   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0 
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       421 
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1265 
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20 
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       48581 
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 13/45) 
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0 
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       1346 
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       260 
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0 

SMART Error Log Version: 1 
ATA Error Count: 1 
    CR = Command Register [HEX] 
    FR = Features Register [HEX] 
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX] 
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX] 
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX] 
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX] 
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX] 
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX] 
    ER = Error register [HEX] 
    ST = Status register [HEX] 
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as 
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes, 
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days. 

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1096 hours (45 days + 16 hours) 
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle. 

  After command completion occurred, registers were: 
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH 
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  04 31 00 02 59 d7 a9 

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were: 
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name 
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  -------------------- 
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      05:01:42.830  FLUSH CACHE EXT 
  61 58 30 38 f9 20 40 00      05:01:42.830  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED 
  61 08 80 08 f9 1b 40 00      05:01:42.829  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED 
  61 08 78 a0 b8 52 40 00      05:01:42.788  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED 
  61 30 70 58 0c 50 40 00      05:01:42.788  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED 

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1 
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t] 

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1 
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS 
    1        0        0  Not_testing 
    2        0        0  Not_testing 
    3        0        0  Not_testing 
    4        0        0  Not_testing 
    5        0        0  Not_testing 
Selective self-test flags (0x0): 
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk. 
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` to your question, you need to install the `smartmontools` package if the command is missing.

Comment: @Freddy It is done

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do to force the root filesystem check (and optionally a fix) at boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400851/what-should-i-do-to-force-the-root-filesystem-check-and-optionally-a-fix-at-bo)

Comment: Apart from the single logged error your disk looks healthy. The problem appears to be somewhere else.

Comment: @Freddy I'm not sure `smartmontools` can be 100% relied upon. I had a similar situation in the past where it said everything was fine, but in reality the disk was toast.

Comment: El Borito how do you switch off your system when you've finished with it?

Comment: @roaima You remind me that I turned off the pc again (forced shutdown), becuase it not turned on. I forgot that detail. But it is not the first time, I turn off my computer in the right way.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I don't understand how to apply it in this specific case

Answer (score 5):

My advice: back up your data now, then replace the drive asap. I had a similar issue a couple of years ago with an old Macbook I was running Linux on. The root filesystem would suddenly go read-only and on reboot I had to run `fsck` every time to fix it. `smartmontools` indicated that everything was fine. I changed the hard disk and the problem went away immediately.

I'm not saying your problem is necessarily the same, but it sounds very similar to what I experienced. Definitely at least back up your data, as a precaution.

Comment: Not convinced about this at all. Look at the Power On hours - 1544 is only two months and even at 8 hours/day it's only six months.

Comment: @roaima I'm not saying this is definitely the problem, but I'm relating an experience I had that seemed very similar. In my experience, `smartmontools` is not 100% reliable and can give false negatives. Besides, manufacturing defects, transportation damage can occur, even if the hours of use seems low.

Comment: @Time4Tea Thanks for your response, at the moment i cannot change my hard disk and I want to learn about these things, because it is not my first pc with problems (the difference is this pc is "new"). I shall try to back up my data. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The same problem happened to me, my Ubuntu 19.10 when restarting had to execute the command:

> fsck -fy /dev/sda2

I started to analyze the logs `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` and realized that always before corrupting the disk, information related to my battery was logged from the `laptop-mode-tools` software that I had installed the day before.

So I decided to uninstall such software and, in my case, it stopped giving me the problem of corrupting the disk.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, I had dual booted **ubuntu 20.04** with **windows 10**. On every start of ubuntu I face the same issue (*fsck the partition with errors*) and after some time I can't even log into ubuntu anymore.

But I can log into the windows and by analyzing (using the [Hard Disk Sentinel Tool](https://www.hdsentinel.com/) ) there I found the there are a lot of bad sectors on my hard disk (bad sector means a physical damage to hard disk and can't be recovered as far as I know).

I replaced my 1 TB HDD with 240 GB SSD and on new SSD I install only ubuntu 21.04 and the problem is gone. HDD of my system was 5+ year old and that's what the life of most of the HDD (I used it extensively as well, pretty much each day).

**Take Away: First make sure the HDD/SSD is in good health.**

Comment: Hi, I inserted my HDD into another computer (older) and the problem seems to be gone. It's pretty weird, one day i'm going to take a look with Hard Disk Sentinel Tool. Thank you