# Root volume fs (ext4) is kernel-remounted at every boot

Tags: linux, kernel, mount, fstab

*[Arch system on UEFI / GPT boot]*

Every time I boot, my box' root volume (located in its own ext4 partition) is re-mounted, something that (****I think****) never occurred before my last update (kernel 5.8.5 -> 5.9.3).

My corresponding `/etc/fstab` line is:

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   /   ext4   errors=remount-ro,relatime,data=ordered,acl,user_xattr   0 1
```

The only related journal log entries are included below. They start with a trace of the first mount logged, and end with the trace log of the re-mount (with no intervening log entries in `journalctl -b` output):

```
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST kernel: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p8): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 251 (systemd-binfmt)
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System. 
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST kernel: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p8): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,data=ordered,acl,user_xattr
Nov 06 09:35:27 HOST systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
```

Any pointers as to why this is happening ? 
It looks as if `systemd` first mounts the `root` partition as is, in order to go through with setting up the Huge Page table, message queuing, kernel debug and trace, before taking the time to correctly mount the `root` partition (/dev/nvme0n1p8) with its specified mount options. This may well be part of the normal boot sequence for our friend `systemd`, but I am not familiar with it.

An *explanation* would be great. Or is it just a case of booting from usb, mounting the volume on `/mnt/` and `fsck`'ing / repairing it ?

Comment: Look into answers here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400851/126755

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak:  From you the content of the provided link, must I understand that you believe I should `fsck` a partition everytime what I described happens ?  Your referenced answer is informative, but as I would not check my root FS every time it mounts (basically at every boot), I ask: do I need _**both**_ the boot option in a `/etc/default/grub.d/local.cfg file` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT fsck.mode=force"` ***and also*** issue cmd `$ LC_ALL=C sudo tune2fs -c 5 /dev/nvme0n1p8` ?

Comment: You only need to edit `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes"` and running `update-grub` and `reboot`