# e2fsck error - fsck.ext2: no such file or directory while trying to open /dev/root

Tags: linux, boot, ext4, fsck, e2fsck

I am working with embedded Linux build with Yocto. My goal is to enforce file checking during each system booting. I've modified the `/etc/default/rcS` file and I've set `ENABLE_ROOTFS_FSCK=yes` and `FSCKFIX=yes`. `fsck` tries to check a rootfs but I get the following error:

```
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/root
Possibly non-existent device?

fsck failed. Please repair manually and reboot. Please note that the root filesystem is currently mounted read-only. To remount it read-write:
   # mount -n -o remount,rw /
CONTROL-D will exit from this shell and REBOOT the system.
```

I see two problems here. First, why `e2fsck` cannot check the file system? Second, why `e2fsck` calls `fsck.ext2` to check the ext4 filesystem? When I use `fsck -n <partition>` after normal boot, it works fine. I get the following log:

```
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Warning! <partition> is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
<partition> clean
```

Thank you in advanced for any help.

**EDIT:** I use Linux built with Yocto with kernel 3.18 and systemVinit.
There are some more methods to force fsck during boot process but they seem to work on systems with systemd. I suppose that e2fsck doesn't know which partition it should check. It tries to check /dev/root instead of my physical partition /dev/mmcblk0p2.

Comment: Possibly related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400851/126755

Comment: After I read the current edit, I suppose I would go for this method, if applicable to your system: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596818/126755

Comment: Also, I would remove the `ENABLE_ROOTFS_FSCK` + `FSCKFIX`. Have to go, wish you luck!

Comment: You should probably post your /etc/fstab and /etc/default/rsS. And I agree with @LinuxSecurityFreak, backout of your changes. Then reboot and examine the contents of /var/log/syslog.