# How to run fsck on boot with BTRFS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk, btrfs, fsck

Although this is very similar to many closed questions, I believe this is *not* a duplicate, as the only answers I can find [seem to be specific to ext4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400927/).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

It's possible, but unnecessary.

According to the [btrfs readthedocs manual page for fsck.btrfs](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fsck.btrfs.html):

> This is not needed for BTRFS.

and continues:

> If you wish to check the consistency of a BTRFS filesystem or repair a
> damaged filesystem, see btrfs-check(8).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @rickhg12hs! If you can point me towards how to run `btrfs-check` on startup, I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: @Slbox I don't think running `btrfs check` at boot time is recommended. Depending on a number of factors, it could take a while and might severely lengthen boot time. Btrfs does not need to clean up journaling files, etc., like some other file systems.

Comment: Maybe not as a regular thing, but if the volume needs to be unmounted to do `btrfs-check` then boot time is the method that's least onerous to the user. The alternative would be a live USB which isn't too slick.

Comment: @Slbox You could `--force` a `btrfs check` while still mounted but perhaps the results might not be reliable if there is filesystem activity, I really don't know.  The default is `--readonly` so it should be safe.  You may also want to consider `btrfs scrub` for periodic filesystem integrity checking.