# Fstab adding data=journal crashed my Linux' ext4 upon boot, how to fix?

Tags: boot, ext4, fstab, crash, readonly

I changed my `/etc/fstab` from:

```
UUID=f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa    /    ext4    errors=remount-ro                        0    1
UUID=4966-E925           /boot/efi       vfat   umask=0077                                         0    1
```

to this:

```
UUID=f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa    /    ext4    data=journal,errors=remount-ro           0    1
UUID=4966-E925           /boot/efi       vfat   umask=0077                                         0    1
```

Effectively adding `data=journal,` before `errors=remount-ro` option. The reasoning was this computer is running a fragile application 24/7, problems are the power cuts longer than my UPS can hold.

---

Upon the next boot the TTY greeted me, suppose I will be able to log in, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. TTYs have ***insanely fast keyboard*** set by default. I tried to log in about 30 times before the final success.
2. If you have numbers in your password or login name, you may want to turn the numlock on.
3. Issue this command, but make sure you use your drive and partition number:

   ```
   sudo mount -o data=ordered,remount,rw /dev/nvme0n1p2 /
   ```
4. Edit your `/etc/fstab` not to contain the `data=journal` part, save it.
5. Reboot.
6. Optional, but recommended step: You may want to check your root filesystem upon boot now, if so, please [refer to answers here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400851/126755), just a summary:

   > To force a `fsck` on every boot on Linux Mint 18.x, use either `tune2fs`, or `fsck.mode=force`, with optional `fsck.repair=preen` / `fsck.repair=yes`, the kernel command line switches.